# C++ accepts int to be elements in a vector of chars

Tags: c++

I am using `Clang` on a mac. I initialise the `vector` with `string`, it raises error as expected

```
std::vector<char> vec{"eqfqa"};
// error: no matching constructor for initialization of 'std::vector<char>'
```

I accidentally initialise the `vector` with `int`:

```
std::vector<char> vec{1, 2};  // No errors reported
for (auto&& item : vec)
  std::cout << item << ' ';  // Nothing printed
```

The program runs successfully but nothing is printed. This surprises me.

Comment: Hint: What is ascii 1 and 2?

Comment: Char is a primitive numeric type like int but with less storage size. The output shows nothing because no symbols are assigned to ASCII codes 1 and 2.

Comment: @Calculuswhiz Everything below 32 is some form of control character.

Comment: Ah ok. I'll delete my comment.

Comment: In C++, every _primitive_, built-in type is implicitly convertible to every other built-in type. In your case, it happens to be the implicit conversion of `int` to `char`. You could have also used double literals such as `123.456`, or a boolean value of `true` and `false` and they would still be converted to type `char`.

Comment: *The program runs successfully but nothing is printed* --.Depends on the code page.   Back in the MSDOS days, the default page (IBM-437) would cause smiley-face characters to be printed for ASCII 1 and 2.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `int` is convertible to a `char` (with loss of precision of course), so the code compiles, but the ASCII codes for 1 and 2 are not printable.

In your first example, a `char const*` is not convertible to a `char`, hence fails to compile.

Answer (score 0):

you discovered two errors at once. The first problem youre having is, that "eqfqa" is a string(in c terminology) or a char*, not a vector of chars. If you wanted to do a list initialization, you would have to do:

```
std::vector<char> vec {'e','q','f','q', 'a'};
```

the second thing is due to inheritance of c. chars are saved as a short integer value and can directly be casted between the two. Thats what happening in your example, it shows the ASCII char of 1 and 2, which both cant be displayed.

Comment: There’s no inheritance at play here. And “short integer” means specific in C++ (namely, `short`), and that’s a *distinct* data type from `char`, and generally has a different storage size, too.

Comment: My bad. char is 1 Byte (without exception?), short int depends on the system.

Comment: Minor point: `"eqfqa"` is a `const char*`, not a `char*`.

Comment: @PeteBecker its a `const char[6]`

Comment: @largest_prime_is_463035818 — the **important** part here is that it’s `const`. If you want to explain array-pointer decay, by all means do so.